# What is the 3D fourier transform of a spherical shell?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to build up intuition about what the fourier transform of a spherical shell will look like but I can't say I'm making much progress.

I've also tried to dumb down the problem in 2D and consider a circle (not a disc).

ie what is the fourier transform of:

$
f = \delta(x, y) \, \forall \, x^2 + y^2 = 1 \\
f = 0, \text{otherwise}
$

And in 3D

$
f = \delta(x, y, z) \, \forall\, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \\
f = 0, \text{otherwise}
$

Comment: Since those functions are $0$ "almost everywhere" - that is, the sphere has measure zero - the Fourier transform is the same as the Fourier transform of the zero function.

Comment: Thomas has the correct answer.  If even means something other than this, he will have to explain.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oops ok, sorry, formally what I meant is probably that it is a Delta function at those locations. I edited the question to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: @GEdgar confused with your "even" comment

Comment: SORRY, misspelled "evan".  $\delta(x,y)$ is nonsensical to me.  A mathematician might say: $\sigma$ is the arc-length measure on the circle; or the surface-area measure on the surface of the sphere, what is the Fourier transform.  That is an interesting question.

Comment: Is the math wording basically saying we want the fourier transform of a spherical shell right? If so I'll copy paste it as an edit in the answer.

Comment: @evan54 What some of the comments mean is that what you wrote is not the same as $\delta(r - R)/(4\pi R^2)$ (in spherical coordinates) which is probably what you want. Unless you formalize the question it is going to be difficult to make progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be the normalized arc-length measure on the circle $\mathbb T$.  The Fourier transform $\mathcal F(\sigma)$ of $\sigma$ makes sense....
$$
\mathcal F(\sigma)(s,t) = \int_{\mathbb T} e^{-2\pi i(sx+ty)} \;d\sigma(x,y)
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2\pi i (s\cos\theta+t\sin\theta)}\,d\theta
=J_0(2\pi\sqrt{s^2+t^2
}\;)
$$
Here $J_0$ is a Bessel function.

More on Fourier transform of a measure: [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/627986/442)

Of course if you know nothing about the theory of measure and integration, this will not mean anything to you.

Comment: indeed i know little about measure theory etc but I think this makes some sense. In 3D it would be $sx + ty + uz$ and then substitute $s, t, u$ with sin$\theta$ cos$\phi$, cos$\theta$ cos$\phi$, sin$\phi$ and do that integral over the full sphere?

Comment: meant substitute $x,y,z$ not $s,t,u$

Answer (score 3):

In 3D: $\frac{\sin(kr)}{kr}$

Source:

[Vembu, S. "Fourier transformation of the n-dimensional radial delta function." The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics 12.1 (1961): 165-168.](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/12/1/165.full.pdf)